# Animate x and y arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation

I have 2 numpy arrays with lenth n, corresponding to x and y coordinates in n times (n snapshots of position).

I've tried to do with the code bellow.

```py
%matplotlib notebook  
# instead of matplotlib inline. It turns the notebook interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation          # 
from IPython.display import display, Image
from IPython.display import HTML
import numpy as np

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()                            # fig is a figure object
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-1*10**8, 1*10**8), ylim=(-1*10**8,1*10**8))      # ax are the axes. They must be kept fixed in all plots
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=1)                 # line holds the graph to nbe drawn in figure fig. Here it is a
                                              # empty graph

# Initialization function: draws first frame on video. (empty box in this case)
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])                     # the line has no data
    return line,
#
# the data to plot
# i indexes the frames of the animation


# Animation function which updates figure data.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    line.set_data(x1[i], y1[i])            # line graph of x and y coordinates
    return line,

# Call the animator.  
# Draws in Fig
# calls animate(i) for every i in frames
# delay between frames in miliseconds
# blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=range(len(x1)), interval=1000, blit=True)

plt.close(anim._fig)

# Call function to create and display the animation
#HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
HTML(anim.to_jshtml())                                       # empty graph
```

If the code worked I would see an animation of the x and y position.

Comment: add `marker="o"` to `ax.plot`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I have other small problem. My array as length 140000 and it takes a long time to animate. I tried anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,frames=range(100), interval=20, blit=True).

Comment: blitting will not help for showing a saved video (jshtml). It would only help in case you show the plot in a GUI.